# How do I plot a graph with x_lims between time h1:m1 and h2:m2

Tags: python, python-3.x, datetime, matplotlib

I'm working on a project with loads of temperature data and I'm currently processing and plotting all of my data. However, I keep falling foul when I try to set x_lims on my plots between a time1 (9:00) and time2 (21:00)

**Data background:**

The sensor has collected data every second for two weeks and I've split the main data file into smaller daily files (e.g. dayX). Each day contains a timestamp (column = 'timeStamp') and a mean temperature (column = 'meanT').

The data for each day has been presliced just slightly over the window I want to plot (i.e. dayX contains data from 8:55:00 - 21:05:00). The dataset contains NaN values at some points as the sensors were not worn and data needed to be discarded.

**Goal:**

What I want to do is to be able to plot the dayX data between a set time interval (x_lim = 9:00 - 21:00). As I have many days of data, I eventually want to plot each day using the same x axis (I want them as separate figures however, not subplots), but each day has different gaps in the main data set, so I want to set constant x lims. As I have many different days of data, I'd rather not have to specify the date as well as the time.

**Example data:**

```
dayX = 
    timeStamp              meanT
    2018-05-10 08:55:00    NaN
             .              .
             .              .
             .              .
    2018-05-10 18:20:00    32.4
             .              .
             .              . 
             .              . 
    2018-05-10 21:05:00    32.0
```

**What I've tried:**

```
    import pandas as pd
    import numpy as np
    import datetime as dt
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    from matplotlib.dates import date2num, DateFormatter

    dayX = pd.read_csv('path/to/file/dayX.csv)
    dayX['timeStamp'] = pd.to_datetime(dayX['timeStamp'], format=%Y %m %d %H:%M:%S.%f')

    fig, ax1 = plt.subplots(1,1)
    ax1.plot(dayX['timeStamp'], dayX['meanT'])
    ax1.xaxis.set_major_formatter(DateFormatter('%H:%M'))
    ax1.set_xlim(pd.Timestamp('9:00'), pd.Timestamp('21:00'))
    fig.autofmt_xdate()

    plt.show()
```

**Which gives:**

[image: empty figure]

If I remove the limit line however, the data plots okay, but the limits are automatically selected

```
    # Get rid of this line:
    ax1.set_xlim(pd.Timestamp('9:00'), pd.Timestamp('21:00'))
    # Get this:
```

[image: full figure, wrong boundaries]

I'm really not sure why this is going wrong or what else I should be trying.

Comment: What if you add the date explicitly? Like: `pd.Timestamp('2018-05-10 09:00')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `timeStamp` is a `datetime` object. All you got to do is pass the datetime objects as the limits.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import datetime as dt
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.dates import date2num, DateFormatter

dayX = df
dayX['timeStamp'] = pd.to_datetime(dayX['timeStamp'], format='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')

fig, ax1 = plt.subplots(1,1)
ax1.plot(dayX['timeStamp'], dayX['meanT'])
ax1.xaxis.set_major_formatter(DateFormatter('%H:%M'))
ax1.set_xlim(df['timeStamp'].min().replace(hour=9), df['timeStamp'].min().replace(hour=21))
fig.autofmt_xdate()

plt.show()
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: This worked for me in the end, I just had to set the upper limit using .max() rather than .min and when I sliced my data, I sliced the exact time window I wanted (dayX = dayX.between_time(start_time='9:00', end_time='21:00').

Comment: @user3168953 Glad you improvised accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to construct a full timestamp object since it'll default to today's date, which has no data in your case.  the following snippet shoudl replace the `ax1.set_xlim` line in your code, and should also work for starting and ending multiday time ranges on specific hours of your choosing.

```
min_h = 9 # hours
max_h = 21 # hours

start = dayX['timeStamp'].min()
end = dayX['timeStamp'].max()

xmin = pd.Timestamp(year=start.year, month=start.month, day=start.day, hour=min_h)
xmax = pd.Timestamp(year=end.year, month=end.month, day=end.day, hour=max_h)

ax1.set_xlim(xmin, xmax)
```